# Solving $T(n)=4T(n/2)+n^2$

Tags: asymptotics, recurrence-relation

I am trying to solve a recurrence by using substitution method. The recurrence relation is:
$$T(n)=4T(n/2)+n^2$$
My guess is $T(n)$ is $\Theta(n\log n)$ (and I am sure about it because of master theorem), and to find an upper bound, I use induction. I tried to show that $T(n)\le cn^2\log n$ but that did not work, I got $T(n)\le cn^2\log n+n^2$.

I then tried to show that, if $T(n)\le c_1 n^2\log n-c_2 n^2$, then it is also $\mathcal O(n^2\log n)$, but that also did not work and I got $T(n)\le c_1n^2\log(n/2)-c_2 n^2+n^2$.

What trick can I use to show that? Thanks.

Comment: the solution should be O(n^2logn).

Comment: Please have a look at our reference questions, especially under the section "Asymptotics".

Comment: Also, did you mean $\Theta(n^2\log n)$ instead? Since you are trying to show $T(n) \le cn^2\log n$ later.

Comment: See [Solving or approximating recurrence relations for sequences of numbers](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/2789/solving-or-approximating-recurrence-relations-for-sequences-of-numbers), as hinted by @Paresh.

Comment: It seems I forgot to link the collection of [reference pages](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/599/reference-questions). Thanks @Juho

Comment: @Juho You also have to mark the question as duplicate!

Answer (score 6):

You must subtract a *lower order term* in order to strengthen your inductive hypothesis: try

$T(n) \leq c_1 n^2 \lg n- c_2 n$ and you will be able to show by substitution that $T(n) = O(n^2 \lg n)$ for appropriate values of the constants ($c_2 > 1$ and $c_1$ big enough to correctly handle the initial conditions).

Answer (score 3):

I always use following approach: Try to avoid master theorem as a recursion solution gives you more insight to the structure of the problem:

[image: Recursion]

Answer (score 1):

That's a recurrence of the form: $T(n)=aT(n/b)+f(n)$. In your case $a=4$, $b=2$, and $f(n)=n^2$. This is case 2 of the master theorem. It follows that $T(n)=\Theta(n^2\log n)$.